# C++ Writing to file or console by argument

Tags: c++, file, printing, arguments, option-type

Ok, so I would like to do something I myself do find rather interseting .. I want an optional argument in my function and this argument would do two things;
1. Decide whether the text is being printed to the console or to a file
2. Print it to a file if that's the case, otherwise to console

I want it to be in the same function because I want very efficient code.
This is how I tried to solve it but obviously doesn't work

```
void Maze::Print_maze(std::string file = "no!ne") const{
    if (file != "no!ne")
        std::ofstream outfile(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < Map.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (file == "no!ne")
                std::cout << Map[i][j];
            else
                outfile << Map[i][j];
        }
        if (file == "no!ne")
            std::cout << std::endl;
        else
            outfile << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For the curious ones .. 
The code is from a maze project I'm working on, I'm generating a randomized maze, solving it and there's also the possibility of reading a maze from a file then solving it.
Now all that remains is to print it to a file. But as said, rather than making two functions, I'd like to merge my normal print to console with print to a file. I'm just wondering how .. Is it possible?
My "Map[][]" is a `vector <vector<char> >`

Answer (score 4):

`void Maze::Print_maze(std::ostream& s = std::cout)`

Then just pass any stream you want to write to.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to have an `std::ostream*` that points to an `std::ofstream`, if you want to write to a file, or `std::cout` if you want to write to the console.

```
std::ostream* outputTarget = &std::cout;

void output(const std::string& message)
{
    *outputTarget << message;
}

void useFileOutput()
{
    static std::ofstream outFile;
    if (!outFile.is_open())
        outFile.open("log.txt");
    outputTarget = &outFile;
}

void useCout()
{
    outputTarget = &std::cout;
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to place the code into a function that takes an `std::ostream&`.  Pass either `cout` or the file stream to the function.

Answer (score 1):

In you situation I would make 3 function, two with the signatures you want to disambiguate and one that actually does the work. This way you get the unification of having one function do the work and the cleanliness of two functions:

```
public:
void Maze::Print_maze(std::ostream& OutputTarget){
   for (int i = 0; i < Map.size(); i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < Map[i].size(); j++)
       {
           OutputTarget << Map[i][j];
       }
       OutputTarget << std::endl;
   }
}

void Maze::Print_maze() const{
   Print_maze(std::cout);
}

void Maze::Print_maze(std::string file) const{
   std::ofstream Output_file(file.c_str());
   Print_Maze(Output_file);
   Output_file.close();
}
```

Passing around references to the base types allows your maze output logic to ignore the actual output type and focus on rendering the maze.

This in some obtuse sense that is unlikely to matter would also be more performant because you would not need to make a series of string comparisons.

More importantly this version with the presentation and business(maze rendering is now a business) logic separate is simpler, therefor easier to read and less bug prone.

Comment: I like this, and there is not really a reason to not just allow _Print_maze to be another Print_maze overload: give the end user the ability to pass in whatever ostream they want. Also (nitpicky, but I used to do it too) you shouldn't name variables/members (including functions) with a leading _ as that is reserved by the standard for the compiler.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I thought that the _ for compiler reserved names was only for items in the global namespace. Either way you are right that there is no good reason not to let the user of the class access to the actual function as an overload and the _ isn't good practice anyway. Have an upvote for critiquing me.

Comment: yup its just bad practice :-P Sharing my painful code reviews with the world

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I read your replies, I'm thankful for all the good comments and efforts you put to help me. I came to a solution and I believe this is the best solution to my problem that I can come up with.
I also added a bit of error-management

```
void Maze::Print_maze(std::string file) const{
    std::ofstream outfile(file);
    // if file is open, write to file otherwise write to console
    std::ostream &out= (!outfile.is_open()? std::cout : outfile);
    // Check if file failed to open
    if(file != "" && (!outfile.is_open()))
        std::cerr << "File failed to open." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Map.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map[i].size(); j++)
        {
                out << Map[i][j];
        }
            out << std::endl;
    }
    if(outfile.is_open())
        outfile.close();
}
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention this ..
My Maze.h file with my class consists of this function declaration:

```
void Print_maze(std::string file = "") const;
```